# Expo : React Native, 'Error starting tunnel: Error: Starting tunnels timed out'

Tags: reactjs, react-native-ios, expo

I am connected to the same network  my device and PC , how can we fix this error ,

After restarting it gives the same error with :

```
Switched to a LAN URL because the tunnel appears to be down. Only devices in the same network can access the app. You can restart the project to try reconnecting.
```

on my device it says

```
Tunnel packager ....exp.not found
```

I am running on windows btw;
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expo and react-devtools do not go together. So if you are using react-devtools, you must uninstall it. This worked for me:

npm uninstall react-devtools -g

But I noticed some other people were successful with this [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/283).

npm uninstall react-devtools --save-dev

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly because your firewall is blocking it. Verify by shutting off the firewall

Answer (score 1):

Try running the ngork.exe in the background.

You can download ngork at [ngork](https://ngrok.com/download)

Tunnel uses ngork. I faced similar issue and running ngork at background solved me the issue. 
Am not sure how it fixed the 'Error starting tunnel' issue.

Hope I fill find it soon.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by examining my order of operations.
Other people at my workplace had managed to set the project up but for some reason I ran into this error.

I was using VSCode debugger and figured out that the emulator needed expo to be open and the project to be open within expo on the simulator before tunnelling was successful. I was attempting to run the debugger without actually opening the app.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, somehow expo was unable to install `@expo/ngrok` library (that it uses internally to create a tunnel) when I click on tunnel option.

You can solve the issue by installing the library globally using npm and restarting the expo metro bundler with `expo start`.

`npm install --global @expo/ngrok`

Answer (score 0):

#### this usually happens when you have an inconsistent internet connection. you can try restarting your wifi/computer & restarting xde. if that doesn’t work, you can try using a different network to connect to the internet. a last resort is connecting your device to the LAN and strong text running from there

Answer (score -1):

This can also happen if you are using a VPN. Turning it off my VPN worked for me.